# Next-Auth SignIn with Credentials not working

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am implemented sign in with email and password in my nextjs app but it is not working. Whenever I trigger the signIn function it returns this -

```
{
error: null
ok: true
status: 200
url: "http://localhost:3000/auth"
}
```

I have tried several versions of next-auth 4 but same problem.

My package.json file -

```
  {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.2.6",
    "@types/react": "18.2.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.18.10",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  },
}
```

[...nextauth].ts file -

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    pages: {
        signIn: '/',
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'credentials',
            name: 'Credentials',
            //@ts-ignore
            async authorize() {
                const user = {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'bilal',
                    email: 'bilal',
                };
                return user;
            },
            credentials: {}
        }),
    ],

    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
    },
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

My login function  -

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

const login = async () => {
        console.log("LOGGING IN")
        await signIn('credentials', {
            redirect: false,
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "1234567890",
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

I searched for next-auth examples and find this one -
https://github.com/AhmedAlqurafi/next-auth-credentials
Ran this repo locally and it is working but when I copy the code from here it doesn't work on my app.